# how to change vat % to 0

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have downloaded an open source project of stock management system. But its default vat % is 13% but I want to be 0% or can I entirely delete this section? By the way this is the codes for vat %

```js
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * 13;
 vat = vat.toFixed(2);
 $("#vat").val(vat);
 $("#vatValue").val(vat);
```

Comment: You're asking how to write `0` instead of `13` ..? Put the cursor after "13", hit backspace twice, and then hit `0`. There are some more advanced ways too. And don't forget to save your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to create a defaultVAT variable that is set to zero and can be manipulated later if you decide to use something different, like this:

```
var defaultVAT = 0;
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * defaultVAT;
    vat = vat.toFixed(2);
    $("#vat").val(vat);
    $("#vatValue").val(vat);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * 13
```

change 13 to 0